# how to link to more then one cell in a different sheet in excel excel

Tags: excel

i'm trying to make a hyperlink that links to three cells in a different sheet. So in there's a box that says Type the cell reference.
I'm trying to link it to cell A2 and A3 and A6. how do i put that together.
I tried (A1,A3,A4) but it gives wrong reference.

Comment: You want a single link to go to three separate cells?

Comment: yes i want them to link to three cells